# What would count as reasonable grounds for refusal of a pet?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, tenancy-rules

I'm currently renting a flat and have been for 6 months now. The tenancy agreement states:

> Not to keep any domestic animals or birds in the Premises without the prior written consent of the Landlord or his local office, such consent not to be unreasonably withheld, delayed, or withdrawn unless subject to the terms of the headlease.

Is there anything I could do to plead my case? And would they still be able to find reason to deny permission?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have covered every issue I can think of that would lead to a reasonable refusal. But I have no way to know what issues may be in the mind of the agents. In the end, all you can do is ask. If the agents refuse, and they don't provide any reason you consider to be reasonable, you could sue, and it will be up to a court to determine if the refusal was reasonable or not.